# Creating a simple Python contact form

Tags: python, forms, cgi, contacts

new to Python.

I am trying to make a contact form for my portfolio site using Python. The form has 4 input fields - first_name, last_name, email, and message. My website is hosted by hostgator.com.

I want the form when submitted to simply send me the info supplied in the 4 fields to my specified email.

After lots of searching I see a lot of Django tuts but I just want a simple form using Python.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! - Mike Rossi

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Import modules from CGI handling 
import cgi, cgitb, smtplib

cgitb.enable()

# Create instance of FieldStorage
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
print("")

# Get data from fields
first_name = form.getvalue("first_name")
last_name = form.getvalue("last_name")
email = form.getvalue("email")
message = form.getvalue("message")

to = "mike.jacob.rossi@gmail.com"
subject = "Comment from MikeTheDev.com" 
mfrom msg['To'] 
to msg['Subject'] 
form['subject'].value

print("Thanks for contacting me! Get back to you soon,%s. ") % cgi.escape(first_name)
```

Comment: have you tried anything? show us your attempt and we can better help you

Comment: what is the error or problem?

Comment: I am not sure I am just wondering if this is the correct way to set it up. Do I have to connect to the host server?

Comment: Any help? Still trying to figure this out..

Comment: this isn't a coding service, if there is a specific problem let us know, otherwise try it out and see if it works

Comment: I tried it out and I get a response that spits out my index.html page as a response.

Comment: i'm also new to python. do i have to create a separate db table for contacts or when you fill a contact form and send it, that goes to the receiver as an email message???

Answer (score 5):

Due to the OP posting this 3 years ago, I came across this question in my attempt to set up a contact page on my portfolio website.
After coming across this question I found this link: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/intro-to-flask-adding-a-contact-page--net-28982.
This should answer your question.